# What did I accidentally enable with a gesture in Photos?

Tags: ipad, photos, sharing, multi-touch, gesture

I was scrolling around in Photos on my iPad trying to find an image. I had one of the images open and was navigating the bottom row thumbnails. There was very briefly a message saying something about “Quick Sharing” that appeared on the top, with a blue coloured icon. The message disappeared very fast and I didn’t see what it said exactly.

I went to Settings and searched for “Quick Sharing” but found nothing. Then I searched online quite a bit trying to find information on any feature named as such, to no avail. I don’t want to have any nearby sharing on because I don’t want to accidentally share my photos with strangers nearby.

Anyone know what this feature exactly is and where can I find the setting to turn it off please? I think it might be brought up by some sort of swiping gesture, or might be an option on some menu that could be brought up by a swiping gesture. Thanks in advance.